# Подскажите,что не так?

Tags: безопасность

Начал учить js( совсем новичок). Решил посмотреть что такое 'prompt'
Ввел данный код в chrome:

```
var name = prompt("enter your name");
console.log("hello" + name +"!");
```

а он мне в ответ выдал: Используя эту консоль, вы можете подвергнуться атаке Self-XSS, что позволит злоумышленникам совершать действия от вашего имени и получать доступ к вашим данным.Не вводите и не вставляйте программный код, который не понимаете.

Я понимаю,что мой вопрос звучит нелепо, но мог ли я как-нибудь схватить вирус таким образом?

Comment: написано же, то чего не понимаешь - не вставлять. Если проблем с пониманием, того что делаешь нет, то и проблем в безопасности нет.

Comment: Я понимаю, но все равно учиться где-то же надо

Comment: Это предупреждение не имеет никакого отношения к данному конкретному коду, оно просто пишется всегда и всем при открытии консоли

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, не мог. Это предупреждение говорит о том, что если ты выполнишь незнакомый код (например, написанный другим) в консоли браузера то это может привести к любым последствиям.
Если ты полностью понимаешь как работает твой код (например, если ты его и написал), то ничего плохого не произойдет.